# jQuery on hover show image with animation

Tags: jquery

I have two images in a `a` tag

```
<a>
<img src="blabla.jpg" class="VisibleImage" />
<img src="lolo.jpg" class="HoverImage" />
</a>
```

by default image which have class `VisibleImage` is visible and `HoverImage` is hidden, but when someone hover over `a` tag then `VisibleImage` is hidden and `HoverImage` will be visible.

I am using this css:

```
a .VisibleImage{display:block}
a .HoverImage{display:none}

 //on hover
a:hover .VisibleImage{display:none}
a:hover .HoverImage{display:block}
```

But I want a animation like `Slide up`, I tried to use css3 but it did'nt worked.
I moved to jQuery and used jQuery `hover()` but I failed. 
Please give me jQuery code

Comment: can we please see the jQuery you are attempting to use. This way we can show you where your going wrong rather than just give you an answer,

Comment: There is multiple ways you can solve this: jQueryUI (which will work cross browsers but will be a bit less smooth) or CSS3 which will work in modern browsers but not the old ones. The solution is not the same as the problem is different. So explain exactly what you want, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, not sure what you want to achieve with slideUp() but this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.HoverImage').slideUp();
$('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.HoverImage').slideUp().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.VisibleImage').slideDown().fadeIn('slow');
    })
});
$('a').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.VisibleImage').slideUp().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.HoverImage').slideDown().fadeIn('slow');
    })
});​
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/QxyH3/

Cheers, 
Shannon

Comment: i have multiple elements having same CSS Class, when I hover over an element all elements contain the same css shows effect, how to run this jquery for current `a` tag???

Comment: I've edited my comment, please if you're going to post something, post it with a greater example of what you're trying to achieve, ie an example page, a propper description..

Answer (score 0):

use css3 transitions to get animation like slideup

```
.HoverImage{
  max-height:0px;
  height:auto;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 2s;
  display:none;
}

a:hover .HoverImage{
   display:block;
    max-height:500px;
}
```

tutorial for css3 transitions

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp